# Unable to use Diff Viewer & Merge Tool using TortoiseGit 2.13 and Beyond Compare 4.4.2

Tags: git, tortoisegit, mergetool, beyondcompare4, tortoisegitmerge

Unable to use Diff Viewer & Merge Tool using TortoiseGit 2.13 and Beyond Compare 4.4.2

[image]

Right click on Folder --> TortoiseGit --> Settings

**Diff Viewer**
**Before**
C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe -e -ub -dl %bname -dr %yname %base %mine

**After**
D:\Beyond.Compare.4.4.2.26348.Portable\BComparePortable.exe %1% %2% /lefttitle="%3%" /righttitle="%4%"

**Merge Tool**
**Before**
C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe /e /ub /fr /wl /wm /dl %bname /dm %tname /dr %yname  %base %theirs %mine /o %merged /ar
**After**
D:\Beyond.Compare.4.4.2.26348.Portable\BComparePortable.exe %1% %2% %a% /mergeoutput=%o% /lefttitle="%4%" /righttitle="%5%" /centertitle="%3%"

Answer (score 1):

Try these paths:

`D:\Beyond.Compare.4.4.2.26348.Portable\BComparePortable.exe %base %mine /lefttitle="%bname" /righttitle="%yname"`

`D:\Beyond.Compare.4.4.2.26348.Portable\BComparePortable.exe %mine %theirs %base /mergeoutput=%merged /lefttitle="%yname" /righttitle="%tname" /centertitle="%bname"`

(If you press `F1` in TortoiseGit Settings, you will get help with variables names and their description.)